# Semantic tagging in Markdown

Tags: markdown

I'd like to take class notes using a simple text editor and Markdown. Is there a way to tag elements of the text to make them machine readable?

For example, I'd like to tag certain words and phrases as "definitions". Then later, I could run some sort of script to display words and their corresponding definitions.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old but I just started to embrace Markdown and found myself asking this same question. I have a markdown document where I write notes on development, mainly C# stuff but also JavaScript and other topics. I think I came up with a pretty good solution; Simply add empty links prefixed with `#` to the post's title like so:

```
### My post title [#mytag]()
```

This allows me to add as many tags as I want, which is useful when a post contains more than one topic. Needless to say, you could add tags within the post itself. Perhaps most importantly to some of us, **it renders nicely!**. Ideally they would be invisible but there is also an advantage to displaying them.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is a good approach if you want to use tags to navigate when reading.

Comment: Even better, one could add `#tag` into the url, like `[#mytag](#tag)`. It adds markdown linting compatibility ;)

The linter: https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/blob/v0.25.1/doc/Rules.md#md042---no-empty-links

Answer (score 4):

There is no specific markdown syntax for definitions (let alone tag). You could probably use the blockquote syntax :

```
> blablabla
```

...or you could simply emphasize the term you are about to define :

```
**word** : a word is a blablabla
```

---

However, html code inside markdown is syntactically correct so you could use  tags with class attributes like this :

```
<div class="definition important">blablabla</div>
```

In that particular case, there are HTML5 tags covering definitions :

```
<dl>
  <dt>Coffee</dt>
    <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
  <dt>Milk</dt>
    <dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply surround the  tag with a specific pattern of your choosing? Like `:mytag:`  or `&mytag&`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Kramdwon](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/syntax.html#span-ials) or [Maruku](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/index.html) to parse your Markdown files you can add classes and ids to inline elements like this:

```
This *word*{:.def} has to be defined. 
→ This <em class="def">word</em> has to be defined.
```

You can try it with [Markdownr](http://markdownr.com/).

But I guess the simpler and more practical way is to just add `<em>`s and do the desired changes later on with a script. Just as proposed by Antoine Gersant.

Answer (score 1):

Quarto (Posit) markdown, which is the same markdown as pandoc and PHP markdown extra, accepts:

```
term
: definition
```

It converts to dt and dd html tags respectively.

Quarto is a very cool tool. Take a look: [Quarto](https://quarto.org)

Answer (score 0):

Markdown supports escaping special characters. While `#foo` is rendered as a first-level heading, `\#foo` is rendered as "#foo".