# Tagging "to-do"s and colouring text in Markdown

Tags: github, markdown

I'm using the GitHub flavoured Markdown on the GitHub wiki, and would like to somehow "tag" paragraphs in need of rewriting or elaboration.

My first thought was to write some kind of note above the paragraph and colour that note red (or any colour besides black, really) for quick recognition, but it appears that Markdown does not support colouring text. I'm already using **bold** to emphasise other things, so I would like to avoid using that.

I realise [a similar question (Semantic tagging in Markdown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783641/semantic-tagging-in-markdown) has been asked previously, but that did not deal with to-do tags. I guess what I'm really looking for is a way of doing this based on someone else's experience as there is no specific syntax for accomplishing what I'm trying to do.

Two questions, then:

1) Why doesn't Markdown support colouring text?

2) Is there any semantically correct way of "tagging" a to-do in a Markdown wiki? If not: any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As-is, Markdown is meant to be more of a replacement syntax for a language such as HTML and, for the most part, doesn't determine any styling for content.

If you want to "tag" something as a to-do item, you could make a line linking to [an itemized task list](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown#task-lists) on its own separate to-do page.

Comment: Thank you! Accepted for the good suggestion -- I'll try "implementing" this into my setup and see how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

1. 'pure' markdown is supposed to be at least fairly style-independent (as with most markup languages). It does provide the pragmatism of inline raw html/latex which if you are only targetting one of them (I'm assuming html given the github tag) are probably the easiest way to do it.
2. Not within markdown markdown. The closest is the class support that various flavours of markdown have added as extensions to the language (personally I use pandocs, although the link you provided offers a couple of extra options). These are obviously harder to use if you are targeting github since you can't control the variant in use.